# Pair within an unsorted Array for a given Sum

Tags: c++, data-structures

Here it is using the `unordered_map` for the hashtable concept but I am not sure how it is doing so without even inserting item into the key value pair of `undered_map`.

This is the code for finding the pairs within an unsorted array.
Here it is using hashtable concept for everyother element.

```
void findPair(int arr[],int n,int x)
{
    unordered_map<int,int> umap;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int temp=x-arr[i];
        if(umap.find(temp)!=umap.end())
        {
            int count=umap[temp];
            for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
                cout<<arr[i]<<" "<<temp<<"\n";
        }
        umap[arr[i]]++;
    }
}
```

Can you please give me some insight how it is inserting and why it is incrementing the count of that value?

Comment: What does this code do?:) What is its purpose?

Comment: It finds number of pairs possible whose sum is a given value(here x)

Answer (score 1):

The map counts the number of times each element occurs in the unsorted array. By default, if you write

```
umap[key]
```

and `key` is not in `umap`, it inserts `key` into `umap` with a default value of `0`. It then returns a reference to the location where the key was stored in the map.

This means that for a new key given by `arr[i]`, the key is inserted into the map when you call `umap[arr[i]]`, and then that value is incremented so that the map registers a count of `1` for that key.

Comment: Also at first we are not inserting the key we are trying to find the diff of sum and arr[i] then how are we comparing it when there is nothing to compare in map until we insert?

Comment: If possible can you explain it a bit more easily or with example? I m new to map